# Automatically create several Google Sheets from a list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to automatically create several Google Sheets from a list. These Google Sheets should follow a **template** (a Google Spreadsheet with several sheets on it).

The list contains the following fields:

Title | ID | Description | Address | Country | Cell_A | Cell_B | Cell C

Example:

Filename | 1 | 'ABC' | '19th street' | 'USA' | Sheet1!A5 | Sheet2!A1 | Sheet2! A2

```
Cell A = in which cell Descrip should be filled
Cell B = in which cell Address should be filled
Cell C = in which cell Country should be filled etc.
```

The title would only be used in the Google Sheets' titles.
The other fields would be used to fill in data in specific sheets of the template

The list is also in Google Sheets (it would be ok to convert it to a csv/xlsx and the like).

I know there is a script to fill in Google Docs using sheets, but I could not find one that can be used to create Google Sheets

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLALWX0_OYs

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  //Title | ID | Description | Address | Country | FolderId | SheetNames csv
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(r[5]);
    let file = folder.createFile('r[0','',MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
    let s = SpreadsheetApp.openById("file.getId()");
    r[6].split(",").forEach(n => {s.insertSheet(n)});
    sh.getRange(i + 1, 1).setValue(ss.getId());
    return [file.getId()];
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks nice for creating new files. But I'm afraid I did not provide the complete information. I need the new files to be based on an existing template (a google spreadsheet with several sheets). Also, the data from the list will be used to fill in specific cells on these sheets. So the list actually would be sth like this
Title | ID | Description | Address | Country | Cell_A | Cell_B | Cell C
Filename | 1 | 'ABC' | '19th street' | 'USA' | Sheet1!A5 | Sheet2!A1 | Sheet2! A2

Cell A = in which cell Descrip should be filled
Cell B = in which cell Address should be filled..

Comment: Well it sounds like I provided a good start and you have some work of your own to do,  But we are all supposed to be programmers here so it should not be to difficult for you the provide the rest of your needs